# How to add @2x, @3x sizes images for a tab bar icon in storyboard

Tags: swift, ios8, storyboard, tabbar

I can't add multiple images with different size for a tab bar icon in storyboard. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images with the different sizes should be named as followed :

- imageName@1x.png
- imageName@2x.png
- imageName@3x.png

Then you can add those three images into your image.xcassets, Xcode will sort them automatically.

In interface builder finally you can select your image in your tab bar item by selectring imageName. The program will choose the right size automatically.

Programmatically you can choose your image with :

```
UIImage(named: "imageName")
```

The right size will also automatically be chosen

Comment: Also good to note that the name for your 'UIImage' is the name of the asset you set in image.xcassets, not the file name of the image itself.